# How to generate pdf from an html template with a React.js frontend?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf

I want to convert a plain HTML with basic CSS to a PDF document. I'm using React.js as my frontend framework. Ideally the conversion will be on the browser instead of the server, to not burden the server in case a lot of clients want to generate pdf documents.

The solutions I found are kind of weird to me. I expected to find a relatively simple library where you can pass a html object and returns a pdf binary data. But what I find is jsPDF that works with a canvas and it looks a bit overcomplicated to me.

It's possible to export the template html to pdf using the browser itself. However, I can't set, for example, a footer this way.

An example html could be like:

```css
/* reset */

*
{
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* content editable */

*[contenteditable] { border-radius: 0.25em; min-width: 1em; outline: 0; }

*[contenteditable] { cursor: pointer; }

*[contenteditable]:hover, *[contenteditable]:focus, td:hover *[contenteditable], td:focus *[contenteditable], img.hover { background: #DEF; box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0.5em #DEF; }

span[contenteditable] { display: inline-block; }

/* heading */

h1 { font: bold 100% sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.5em; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; }

/* table */

table { font-size: 75%; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 2px; }
th, td { border-width: 1px; padding: 0.5em; position: relative; text-align: left; }
th, td { border-radius: 0.25em; border-style: solid; }
th { background: #EEE; border-color: #BBB; }
td { border-color: #DDD; }

/* page */

html { font: 16px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif; overflow: auto; padding: 0.5in; }
html { background: #999; cursor: default; }

body { box-sizing: border-box; height: 11in; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 0.5in; width: 8.5in; }
body { background: #FFF; border-radius: 1px; box-shadow: 0 0 1in -0.25in rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

/* header */

header { margin: 0 0 3em; }
header:after { clear: both; content: ""; display: table; }

header h1 { background: #000; border-radius: 0.25em; color: #FFF; margin: 0 0 1em; padding: 0.5em 0; }
header address { float: left; font-size: 75%; font-style: normal; line-height: 1.25; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
header address p { margin: 0 0 0.25em; }
header span, header img { display: block; float: right; }
header span { margin: 0 0 1em 1em; max-height: 25%; max-width: 60%; position: relative; }
header img { max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
header input { cursor: pointer; -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; height: 100%; left: 0; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; }

/* article */

article, article address, table.meta, table.inventory { margin: 0 0 3em; }
article:after { clear: both; content: ""; display: table; }
article h1 { clip: rect(0 0 0 0); position: absolute; }

article address { float: left; font-size: 125%; font-weight: bold; }

/* table meta & balance */

table.meta, table.balance { float: right; width: 36%; }
table.meta:after, table.balance:after { clear: both; content: ""; display: table; }

/* table meta */

table.meta th { width: 40%; }
table.meta td { width: 60%; }

/* table items */

table.inventory { clear: both; width: 100%; }
table.inventory th { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }

table.inventory td:nth-child(1) { width: 26%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(2) { width: 38%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(3) { text-align: right; width: 12%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(4) { text-align: right; width: 12%; }
table.inventory td:nth-child(5) { text-align: right; width: 12%; }

/* table balance */

table.balance th, table.balance td { width: 50%; }
table.balance td { text-align: right; }

/* aside */

aside h1 { border: none; border-width: 0 0 1px; margin: 0 0 1em; }
aside h1 { border-color: #999; border-bottom-style: solid; }

/* javascript */

.add, .cut
{
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8rem;
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;  
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 0.6em;
}

.add, .cut
{
    background: #9AF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#00ADEE 5%, #0078A5 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00ADEE 5%, #0078A5 100%);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border-color: #0076A3;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.333);
}

.add { margin: -2.5em 0 0; }

.add:hover { background: #00ADEE; }

.cut { opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: -1.5em; }
.cut { -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease-in; }

tr:hover .cut { opacity: 1; }

@media print {
    * { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }
    html { background: none; padding: 0; }
    body { box-shadow: none; margin: 0; }
    span:empty { display: none; }
    .add, .cut { display: none; }
}

@page { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Invoice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="license" href="https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license/">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Invoice</h1>
            <address contenteditable>
                <p>Jonathan Neal</p>
                <p>101 E. Chapman Ave<br>Orange, CA 92866</p>
                <p>(800) 555-1234</p>
            </address>
            <span><img alt="" src="http://www.jonathantneal.com/examples/invoice/logo.png"><input type="file" accept="image/*"></span>
        </header>
        <article>
            <h1>Recipient</h1>
            <address contenteditable>
                <p>Some Company<br>c/o Some Guy</p>
            </address>
            <table class="meta">
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Invoice #</span></th>
                    <td><span contenteditable>101138</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Date</span></th>
                    <td><span contenteditable>January 1, 2012</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Amount Due</span></th>
                    <td><span id="prefix" contenteditable>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="inventory">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Item</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Description</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Rate</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Quantity</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Price</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="cut">-</a><span contenteditable>Front End Consultation</span></td>
                        <td><span contenteditable>Experience Review</span></td>
                        <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span contenteditable>150.00</span></td>
                        <td><span contenteditable>4</span></td>
                        <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <a class="add">+</a>
            <table class="balance">
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Total</span></th>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Amount Paid</span></th>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span contenteditable>0.00</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Balance Due</span></th>
                    <td><span data-prefix>$</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </article>
        <aside>
            <h1><span contenteditable>Additional Notes</span></h1>
            <div contenteditable>
                <p>A finance charge of 1.5% will be made on unpaid balances after 30 days.</p>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know a good solution for what I want? Converting a html with embedded styling to pdf? I'm willing to pay for a library, but I've to try it out first before I pay.

Comment: You can look at: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ and possibly https://react-pdf.org/

Comment: Also https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js uses html2canvas in combination with jspdf.

Answer (score 0):

This download PDF worked in my case

```
const downloadPDF = () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF({
      orientation: 'portrait',
      unit: 'mm',
      format: [297, 210] // A4 page size in mm
    });
  
    // Get the resume template element
    const resumeTemplate = resumeRef.current;
  
    // Convert the resume template element to a canvas
    html2canvas(resumeTemplate, {allowTaint: true, useCORS: true, scale: 2.8 }).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.1);
  
      // Set the image size and position to fit the page
      var imgWidth = 210;
      var pageHeight = 295;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;
      var position = 0;
      
      // Add the canvas image to the PDF document
      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      
      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      }
  
      // Save the PDF document
      doc.save('resume.pdf');
    });
  };

return (
<div>
  <button onClick={downloadPDF}>Generate Resume PDF</button>
  <div ref={resumeRef} style={{width:'60%', margin:'5rem'}}>
    {/* Render your resume template component here */}
    <ResumeTemplate/>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).